# How do I construct the eigenvectors of the Hadamard gate using Quantum Gates?

Tags: hadamard, linear-algebra

How do I use quantum gates offered on IBM quantum to construct either eigenvector of the Hadamard gate?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the vectors you're trying to create are real. A great way of creating a real vector is to apply a $Y$ rotation,
$$
R_Y(\theta)|0\rangle=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|0\rangle+\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|1\rangle.
$$
So, take the state you want to create and normalize it. For example,
$$
|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}}((1+\sqrt{2})|0\rangle+|1\rangle).
$$
Now solve for $\theta$, i.e.
$$
\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}}.
$$
Thus, $\theta=\pi/4$. (If that's not so obvious, use the double angle formula,
$$
\cos\theta=\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^2-1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.)
$$

Hence, the circuit you want to run is simply $R_Y(\pi/4)|0\rangle$. I'm assuming you can convert this into qiskit commands.